# When do you gain access to Kaze's child?

Tags: fire-emblem-fates

I just beat Chapter 11 of Birthright and have gotten Kaze and Azura to S rank support. I was able to access and beat Paralog 3 to gain Azura's child but do not seem able to have access to the paralog for Kaze's child.

When do I gain access to Kaze's child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is the birthright version since the Paralogue is not unlocked. With that said, once you complete chapter 15 Paralogue 6 will be unlocked (Called Herbal Remedy) prompting the access to Kaze's daughter Midori. Just as long as you don't kill Kaze that is... hehehehe.

Anyways, hope this helps ^-^